# linux screen - kill only if it exists (jenkins job)

Tags: jenkins, kill, gnu-screen

I'm configuring complex jenkins jobs using linux screens. To create a new screen I run:

```
screen -md -S jenkins_job
```

then goes some other work and finally to destroy existing screen I run:

```
screen -S jenkins_job -X quit
```

But it may happen in jenkins that the script will fail somewhere inbetween and abort immediately. Then the screen termination command will not be executed and screens will be kept alive. So in the beginning of the job I'd like to make sure that all screens are destroyed. If I use `screen -S jenkins_job -X quit` on a non-existent job shell will return error code and jenkins script will fail as well.

Is there any way to conditionally destroy a screen (i.e. destroy screen if it exists otherwise do nothing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to put the termination code into a `trap` invocation:

```
trap 'screen -S jenkins_job -X quit' QUIT TERM INT EXIT
```

Comment: I run this trap in the beginning of the job to make sure the screen will be destroyed no matter what was the overall jenkins job result (QUIT or TERM - success or fail) - is that right?

Comment: I forgot, if you also want to handle normal termination, add the `EXIT` signal